# Sell order in Bter is incorrect

Tags: exchange-rate, exchange-fees, exchange-order, bter

In [Bter](https://bter.com/) I created a sell offer with DOGE/BTC, it seems the calculation is wrong. They have not deducted the transaction fee. I have included 2 screen shots and anybody know the same or experience the same kindly clarify this.

**Before creating sell order**

**Sell DOGE**

[image: before creating order]

**After creating sell order**

[image: after creating order]

My question is Is transaction fee deducted in this transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends also on your BTC balance AFTER the sale. It seems that there is indeed 1000 DOGE subtracted from your balance, so that is correct. If there has been 0.00061 added to your BTC balance, then no fees have been deducted. If 0.00061*(1-0.0018) = 0.000608902 have been added to your BTC balance, then the fees have been deducted from your received currency.

This is general behavior on exchanges. It is more user friendly to specify the exact amount of sold (and deducted from balance) and deduct the fee from the receiving currency.

Comment: Hey Mathias- It is ok. But my question is have they deducted the transaction fee of 0.18%

Comment: Well, it seems that there are 1000 DOGE deducted (assuming the screenshots are before and after trade, nothing else). So you sold 1000 DOGE -> BTC. With the current bid price, you would get 0.00061 BTC in return. If you got 0.00061 BTC, they didn't deduct any fee. If you got 0.00061*(1-0.0018) = 0.000608902 BTC, then they deducted the fee from your received BTC.

Comment: Did you notice the transaction fee is in terms of DOGE?

Comment: Yes, so I would say that you would have to pay 1001.8 DOGE . But according to your screenshots, that is not the case. Therefor I looked at the only other option: BTC.

Comment: yes. You are correct now. Is this behavoir correct. Do you have account with bter?

Comment: Furthermore it is more convenient to subtract the fee from the received currency. If you have for example 1000 DOGE, and you want to sell it all, you'll first have to calculate how much DOGE (~998.2) you'll have to sell to be precize 1000 including the fee. Otherwise there would be dust everywhere in your account on all traded currencies ;). I don't have an account on Bter, but it works like this on other exchanges I believe

Comment: yes. But here ..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15131/discussion-between-jsd-and-mathias711).